# Rare error on a Fragment with a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I do not know how to explain this. My app overnight has stopped "working." It consists of a `RecyclerView` with several items and a search bar at the top. All this within a `fragment` belonging to an `activity`.
Well, if I click on an item it does nothing and the search engine only works if I hit a very small part attached to the right edge.
I can scroll, if I go to another activity and come back, sometimes, if I click on an `item` it works correctly.

The debug version works correctly, but the release version has all these errors.

Very rare.

**Edit:**

I have discovered that it may be for having a CardView as a root in layout item

---

[image]

RecyclerItemClickListener:

```
private RecyclerItemClickListener recyclerItemClickListener = new RecyclerItemClickListener() {
        Transition.init(getActivity(), FichaAnimalActivity.class, Consts.ARG_ANIMAL, adapter.getItem(position), Consts.ARG_USER, mUser);
    }
};

public static void init(Activity current, Class cls, String n1, Serializable o1){
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    Intent i = new Intent(current, cls);
    b.putSerializable(n1, o1);
    i.putExtras(b);
    current.startActivity(i);

    current.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
}
```

ItemAdapter:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            final Animal animal = lista.get(position);
            AnimalHolder h = ((AnimalHolder) holder);

            .....

            h.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    recyclerItemClickListener.onItemClick(position);
                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: maybe provide us with your code snippet of the fragment.

Comment: It is very long, but yesterday it worked fine, not today. I added the code from the onclicklistener, it's very simple. The strange thing is that if I use the debug version it works perfectly, but the release version does not.

Comment: are you attaching any click events to your `itemView` inside the ViewHolder?

Comment: Yes, I do it. See code above.

Comment: I have discovered that it may be for having a CardView as a root in layout item. Removing it, its works.